# Simplifying series of $20^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Just wondering how we know the following series is calculated:

$$100\sum_{i=2}^n 20^{-i}$$

My notes gave me the solution $\frac{5}{19}(1−20^{1−n})$ without saying how or showing any working.

Thank you

Comment: It's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$S:=a^2+a^3+a^4+a^5=a(a+a^2+a^3+a^4)=a(a+S-a^5)$$

so that

$$(1-a)S=a(a-a^5).$$

You can generalize to your case.

Comment: Why not factoring out $a^2$?

Comment: @Bernard: I am minimizing the transformations so that the OP better sees what is going on.